# “Can you tell me where did you buy it?”

Tags: word-order, questions, subject-auxiliary-inversion

Is it correct to say the following as an indirect question?

> Can you tell me where did you buy it?

or should it be

> Can you tell me where you bought it?

Comment: related: [“I can't understand what does it mean.” vs “I can't understand what it means.”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/217202) and [reported speech for 'what do you do?'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/158017) and [“Do you know what IS IT?” vs “Do you know what IT IS?”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41628/)

Answer (score 2):

> Can you tell me where did you buy it?

This doesn't work - although you could say "Can you tell me - where did you buy it?" if you were adding a significant pause and making it into two independent clauses.  But then both would be direct questions.

> Can you tell me where you bought it?

Correct.

There's also "Can you tell me where you *did* buy it?" but you would only say this in certain circumstances (for example, where the addressee had previously denied buying it at a particular location).